# How to place datatable in the middle and not take up the whole width

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am developing website with Angular5. One of the components shows data in a [Datatable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome).

```
<div>
  <table datatable class="table row-border hover" *ngIf="this.temp_var">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Door ID</th>
        <th>Powerup Days</th>
        <th>Cycle Count</th>
        <th>Error Code</th>
        <th>Error Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let rec of this.data">
        <td>{{rec.doorId}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.days}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.controllerCycleCount}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.errCode}}</td>
        <td>{{rec.errName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The table is taking up the whole width of the page.

[image]

So I changed the width of table to 80%.

```
<table datatable class="table row-border hover" *ngIf="this.temp_var" style="width:80%">
```

Now the table itself got shrunk horizontally, but all the other things like the search box, pages, etc, are still at the far ends.

[image]
Is there way to shift them to align with the actual width of the table? I tried to move the `width=80%` to outer `<div>`, but it didn't help.

Comment: can you add your code in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @Chellappan What is that? I got DNS error

Comment: it's online editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add 80% width to the div which wraps table along with search and entries boxes (div with id `DataTables_Table_0_wrapper` in my example)

```
<div id="DataTables_Table_0_wrapper" 
     class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer" 
     style="width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;">
  <div class="dataTables_length" id="DataTables_Table_0_length">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="DataTables_Table_0_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
    ...
  </div>
  <table class="row-border hover dataTable no-footer" 
         datatable="" 
         id="DataTables_Table_0" 
         role="grid" 
         aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
    ...
  </table>
```

`width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;` on this wrapper div should make it 80%wide and centered:

[image]

Comment: It turns out I was missing `dataTable` class for my table. After I added it `table class="row-border hover dataTable no-footer"` and have the `div` set as 80%, it worked.